# How to convert byte[] to Bitmap without a loss in quality

Tags: android, image-processing

My aim is to

1. Capture bytes from the camera *onPictureTaken*
2. Convert the byte[] to a Bitmap *BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray*
3. Save the Bitmap

I have a problem with step 2. This step for some reason makes the picture contain jagged edges and a loss of quality. If I do step 1 and save the bytes to a file directly (without step 2) then the image looks a lot better.

How do I convert bytes to a bitmap (step 2) without losing quality?

```
    @Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] byteData, Camera camera) {
    String filePath = "PATH_TO_IMAGE_FILE";

    //Save bytes directly
    {
        File pictureFile = new File(filePath + ".fromBytes");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(byteData);
            fos.close();


        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.d( "File not saved: " , error.getMessage());

        }
    }

    //convert to bitmap -> convert to bytes -> then save
    {
        //I think this is where is loses quality ??
        Bitmap decodedBitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteData, 0, byteData.length);
        //

        ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        decodedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, blob);
        byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
        File pictureFile = new File(filePath + ".fromBitmap");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(bitmapdata);
            fos.close();


        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.d( "File not saved: " , error.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "This step for some reason makes the picture contain jagged edges and a loss of quality" -- not by default. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you have tried.